# Use elasticsearch property as regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Our HTTP routes are being stored in elasticsearch, since we have a huge amount of routes for our application.

In the given [examples of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) for filtering by regex, it's possible to match a regex against a property value. But since our route URL's can be a regex itself (e.g.: /news/(d+)/.+.html ), we would like to match the property value (being the regex) against a given string.

So, as pseudo JSON filter example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp_property":{
      "property": "route_settings.regex"
      "subject": "/news/12/our-article.html"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there somebody out there, having experience with this particular situation?

Comment: A regex is a string, you can write regexes for regexes as well! Inception at it's finest.

Comment: True that, but how should I direct ES to test the regex (defined in the document) on a subject defined in the query filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that ES **cannot use a regex defined in documents**, as stating:

> Regular expression constants are directly supported. To ensure fast
>   performance, this is the only mechanism for creating patterns. Regular
>   expressions are always constants and compiled efficiently a single
>   time.

*[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-syntax.html#patterns)*

In this particular situation, routing with routes defined in ES is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way where you can out-of-the-box compile regexes that are in the document.

Simply take the add another OR clause where a pattern might be in an escaped form.

In your example, we can change the actual pattenr \d+ with an OR of an escaped one. 
/news/**((d+)|\d+)**/.+.html

http://rubular.com/r/ySzQqAsMFm